# Casting Generic Parameters as Dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, func

I'm writing a rule based mock data generator.  But to save time I've decided to use a dynamic container to store rules.

```
    public void AddGlobalRule<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property, Func<Faker, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic> rule)
        where T : class
    {
        var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;
        this.AddRawRule(typeof(T), rule, propertyName);
    }

    public void AddRawRule(Type entityType, Func<Faker, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic> rule, string propertyName)
    {
        if (false == this._ruleMap.ContainsKey(entityType))
        {
            this._ruleMap.Add(entityType, new RuleSet());
        }

        var ruleset = this._ruleMap.Get(entityType);
        ruleset.Add((propertyName, rule));
    }
```

The issue is that this code doesn't have intellisense, I would really like to write the function like so:

```
public void AddGlobalRule<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property, Func<Faker, T, T, TProperty> rule)
    where T : class
{
    var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;
    var dynamicRule = rule as Func<Faker, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>;
    this.AddRawRule(typeof(T), dynamicRule, propertyName);
}
```

**Edit for clarity:**

If I use `Func<Faker, T, T, TProperty> rule` as the input into the function, when I use it

```
 generator.AddGlobalRule<Employee, string>(x => x.Name, 
    (f, previous, current) => {
       //If I use Dynamic I don't have intellisense here
       return current.FirstName + current.LastName;
    })
```

However when I try to cast the dynamic rule is null,

```
var dynamicRule = rule as Func<Faker, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>;
```

How can I cast to the my rule, so that I can preserve intellisense?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you expecting dynamic code to have Intellisense in your editor? The point of dynamic programming is to resolve types at runtime.

Comment: I'm trying to abstract the use of dynamic to be only internal to my factory.  This way when building rule intellisense will be there, I've updated the question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Right. Casting to `Func<Faker, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>` is effectively the same as casting to `Func<Faker, object, object, object>`, just with dynamic resolution. So you can't do that because the inputs to `Func` are contravariant not covariant (a delegate that takes an arg of `T` will not also accept an argument of `object`).

(I'd ask yourself why you store in the map with `dynamic` arguments and not just plain old `object`s? Are you actually consuming these dynamically?)

Anyhow, you need to wrap your delegate in something that downcasts to the required types like:

```
Func<Faker, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic> dynamicRule = (a, b, c) => rule(a, (T)b, (T)c);
```

Comment: Its a bit complicated to explain why it needs to be dynamic, but basically I create rules for open generics, which I will only know a property name at runtime.  e.g Key, we have extensions on top of EF which type a key to its entity type e.g (if you had an Entity Employee) it would have a key => EntityKey<Employee, Int>, because of this when you are operating on Object, accessing the property Key wont exist.  and using reflection to cast it to its appropiate type would be trouble some.

Comment: Also, there are places in the generator which use expressions.  Casting to Object, will create an Implicit Convert() internal to the expression.   I've ran into issues where that cast causes problems, so then I would have to revisit the expressions and strip the convert off of them.